# Posting credentials to web API using Fiddler (not Basic Auth)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, asp.net-web-api2

I've created my first ASP.Net Web API which receives posted credentials and returns a ClaimsPrincipal:

**Credentials.vb**

```
Public Class Credentials
    Public Property UserName as String
    Public Property Password as String
End Class
```

**MyController.vb**

```
    <Route("v1/login")>
    <OverrideAuthorization>
    <HttpPost>
    Public Function Login(c as Credentials) As IHttpActionResult
        Dim cp As ClaimsPrincipal = DataBaseLogin.GetDataBasePrincipal(c.UserName, c.Password)
        ' removed for brevity ...
        Return Ok(cp)
    End Function
```

In Fiddler I am trying to construct a `POST` to this method:

```
POST http://localhost:58442/v1/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58442
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 35

{"Username":"foo","Password":"bar"}
```

The method is hit (breakpoint trigger break) and variable `c` is typed as `Credential` but the values of `c.UserName` and `c.Password` in the method are both `Nothing`.

**Update**

Solved it.  `Content-type` must be `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, because of the simple types (string parameters), Web API is expecting these parameters from the URI and for that reason you are getting 404.

Change the action method some thing like this (sorry about C#).

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("v1/login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(Cred c)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class Cred
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Also, include `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the request. That should work. BTW, you can use `[FromBody]` against the string parameter but then you cannot use two, since body can be used only once. In case you have one parameter, you can use that instead of a complex type (class).

Comment: Thanks @Badri .  I've updated the code as I still can't read in the values.  Some more help would be appreciated please.

Comment: Cancel that comment, I've fixed it and will update the question.  `Content-Type` must be `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`